# Google Data Studio and BigQuery custom SQL with Parameters

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

For a quick POC, I am creating a basic report in Google Data Studio using a Custom SQL Big Query connector that has parameterized query like this
SELECT LOCATION, ANSWER_TEXT FROM `proj-A.sm.RESPONSE` WHERE LOCATION = @LOCATION_PARAM;
LOCATION_PARAM is a drop down list.
On the Data Studio end, EDIT mode, I can see the parameter show up under DATA section with correct options. When I click on the option query returns results properly and results show up on the report in EDIT mode. But for some reason when I go to the VIEW context (I assume that is a preview mode) or share link there is no parameter drop down. Based on documentation, I have tried adding a drop down control but cannot figure out how to attach the parameter to that control. Either Google's documentation does not state that clearly or I am looking at the wrong place. Any help is absolutely appreciated. BTW I am super new to BigQuery and Data Studio.

Comment: Hey, Did you get the solution of this question?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. In Data studio, I ended up creating a blended data source and added a drop down to filter field values. It seems to be a more elegant solution and compliant to Data Studio.

Answer (score 0):

There is a control for drop down (Top tool bar -> Add a control -> Drop Down list) . Drag it down, and in its properties on the right side, under Data, you would see a control field option. Select your parameters there to link the drop down selected value to the parameter passed to the query.

It works for me, but I have another issue - it works perfectly in the Edit Mode,but not in the view mode. Not sure why that is.